# q, w = 1, 2 if 1 < 2 else 2, 1; ValueError: too many values to unpack. Why?

Tags: python, if-statement, iterable-unpacking

As stated in the title

```
q, w = 1, 2 if 1 < 2 else 2, 1
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

What's going on here??

Comment: Use parentheses to avoid this issues `q, w = (1, 2) if 1 < 2 else (2, 1)`

Comment: Just try it out to see what happens: `>>> 1, 2 if 1 < 2 else 2, 3` leads to `(1, 2, 3)`

Comment: I wonder what we did in the old times when there was no one around to tell us which value a simple expression has. Oh, I forgot: we just tried it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you inspect

```
1, 2 if 1 < 2 else 2, 1
```

then you see that python will interpret it like

```
(1, 2 if 1 < 2 else 2) , 1
```

and you will end up with `(1, 2, 1)` which contains too much values for 2 variables of `q, w`

Because python accepts first comma after conditional (`1 < 2`) as the end of *single line if-else statement* and append *after-the-comma* section  to the resulting value set.

A parenthesis at the last value set will be enough

```
q, w = 1, 2 if 1 < 2 else (2, 1)
```

But it would definitely be better to use parenthesis for both

```
q, w = (1, 2) if 1 < 2 else (2, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
q, w = (1, 2) if 1 < 2 else (2, 1)
```

Should solve your issue. Although I would not write code that way as it is harder to read.

Comment: @Liarez If you're downvoting because of that, you should just put your own answer down as well, even if it's identical.

Comment: @Evert I think this question is low quality to deserve an answer, just google 5 secs or try the code and anyone can get the answer, that's why I didn't answer the question, and yes, I downvote because 2 min after I posted my comment I read this answer that is identical

Comment: @Liarez, It looks identical because it is one line of code. You want the credit for this, it is all yours

Comment: hahaha @theAlse I'm not looking for any credit, for that I didn't answer the question for the same reason you're saying, it's 1 line of code. If I were looking for credit I would anwer the question like you did

Comment: -1 You should explain why your answer works, not just paste one liners.